# Word/phrase/idiom/expression for "keep in the back of my mind"(essentially, some idea/concept kept as secondary/ something to be aware off?

Tags: phrases, expressions, idioms

I'm trying to find a Word/phrase/idiom/expression for "keep in the back of my mind"(essentially, some idea/concept kept as secondary/ something to be aware off. )

To elaborate, Let me recollect the following dialogue from the film called "Vice"

Republican candidate George W Bush:  "If I lose the Presidential election then maybe I can become Commissioner of Baseball"

Former Secretary of Defense Dick Cheney:  "But the point is to win the election"

Republican candidate George W Bush: "I'll keep that in the back of my mind"

(Side Note from me:  I'm just thinking out loud.  Is "incidentally" or "By the way" a good word/phrase? )

Comment: Who is thinking out loud? You, Mr Bush or Mr Cheney? I don't see its relevance to the question.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking out loud.

Comment: I don't understand the question, because "keep (smth) in the back of (smby's) mind" *is* a "phrase/idiom/expression" that means exactly that. Do you think it somehow misses the mark or that there's something wrong with it? There are others that are similar but nuanced, like "put a pin in that," but if the reason you're asking for an alternative is for slightly different effect, then you need to explain what effect that is, what nuance you seek that "keep (smth) in the back of (smbdy's) mind" fails to evoke for anyone to be able to answer your question properly.

Answer (score 1):

One phrase is ***to bear in mind***

[Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/bear-something-in-mind#:%7E:text=From%20Longman%20Dictionary%20of%20Contemporary,some%20children%20will%20need%20help.) says:

> **bear (something) in mind**
> to remember a fact or piece of information that is important or could be useful in the future
> keep (something) in mind
> bear in mind (that)
> *Bear in mind that some children will need help.*

> Examples from the Corpus
> bear (something) in mind
> • Thanks, I'll **bear that in mind**.
> • I said I would **bear his suggestion in mind**.
> • If he had ... no conclusions yet, just **bear it in mind**.
> • My right hon. Friend should **bear that in mind**.
> • The Prime Minister I will certainly **bear that in mind**.
> • The problem is largely an insuperable one, and all we can do at this stage is to **bear it in mind**.
> • Tourists must **bear in mind** that they are visitors in another country.
> • Mr. Clarke Any intelligent parent, intelligent governor or intelligent newspaper person will **bear it in mind** that various factors influence results.
> • Thus, firms entering overseas markets must **bear this in mind** when introducing new products or services.
> • It is important that we **bear these differences in mind** when we attempt to analyse the formal nature of public sector organisations.

Comment: Yes, and we bear or keep things **in mind**, not in the back of my mind.